# modified planet outline and orbitals in smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, flow-charts, smartdiagram

after reading the documentation of smart diagram I could have done a very simple approach but I need more customization over the orbitals and outline of the planets and satellites , thank you for your help

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, positioning}




\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{outline=blue,planet color=orange!60, distance planet-satellite=4cm,satellite size/.initial={2.5cm},satellite text width=2cm,planet color={black!60}}
}
\smartdiagram[connected constellation diagram]
{Material Property \\analysis,Degradation detection,Molecular property prediction,Nano materials analysis}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `more customisation` - what does it mean please

Comment: @BROK your code does not compile

Comment: I updated my post I hope it answers both your inquiries

Comment: Look at the red "4" at the top right. It tells you that there are errors in your document. You have to fix them, otherwise your document won't compile. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document. What you see is not necessarily usable output.

Comment: General rule about the smartdiagram package: if the output happens to be what you are looking for, fine, use it as it makes life easy. If you need to make customisations, you are usually better off to create the diagram in tikz.

Comment: You still haven't said what 'more customisation' means. What exactly do you want to change and how? Is the last image your target? An example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if that's what you are looking for:

- `standalone` class creates a pdf, which you can include like an image via package `graphicx`
- each Tikz diagram resides in the `tikzpicture` environment
- followed by `[ ]` that's the place where you can define the styles you need
- draw orbit first to avoid it draws over the rest
- put `\node`s, containing your text (if you give them names, like `(C)`, you can reference them later, if needed)
- using polar coordinates `(angle:radius)` makes it easy to place
- using `\\` AND `align=center` as style is one way to control multilines in nodes

**I suggest** looking up all `Tikz` commands in the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) in parallel.

About the **self-defined styles**:

- `rim` sets the outer tealish rim of the text bubbles
- `sun` and `plnt` reuse this, AND put the `align=center` for multilines
- IF sun and planets would have differed very much in radii (calculated by Tikz), putting `minimum width=3cm` or similar there lets you vary them; but it worked out nicely
- `orbit` tells how thick etc. the orbit circle should appear

**Customization** can be done this way:

- change parameters within the styles, like color, line width etc.
- change elements, their positions etc. via `\draw`, `\node` etc.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    % ~~~ self defined styles for the text bubbles ~~~~~~
    rim/.style ={circle,draw=teal,fill=white,line width=2pt},
    sun/.style ={rim,align=center},
    plnt/.style={rim,align=center},
    % ~~~ making life a bit easier for the orbit ~~~~~~
    orbit/.style={line width=12pt,draw=teal!80!gray!40},
 ]
    % ~~~ draw orbit first, so universe prints over it ~~~~~~~~
    \draw[orbit]       (0,0) circle [radius=4cm];
    
    % ~~~ sun and planets ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[sun]  (C) at (0,0) {Material Property\\Anlysis};
    
    \node[plnt] (D) at ( 90:4) {Degradation\\detecion};
    \node[plnt] (M) at (210:4) {Molecular\\property\\prediction};
    \node[plnt] (N) at (-30:4) {Nano\\materials\\analysis};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**EXAMPLE:**

Just change here

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    % ~~~ self defined styles for the text bubbles ~~~~~~
    rim/.style ={circle,draw=teal,fill=white,line width=2pt},
    sun/.style ={rim,align=center,minimum width=40mm}, % <<<
    plnt/.style={rim,align=center},
    % ~~~ making life a bit easier for the orbit ~~~~~~
    orbit/.style={line width=20pt,draw=orange!80!gray!40}, % <<<
 ]
```

to obtain

[image: result2]

Comment: what do u mean by 'the radii calculated by tikz' ?

Comment: In Tikz nodes have a so called shape. The default is rectangular, but you can change e.g. to circle. If you use option draw, like \node[draw] … the shape is drawn in the color specified (default is black). Tikz determines size of shape from its content. That‘s what I referred to. Reduce one of the texts to a single character to see this effect.